# C# nullable DateOnly Linq how to?

Tags: c#, linq, nullable

I have a class eg. Range which has two DateOnly property, begin and end. The end property is optional so it's nullable. (open ended range)
eg.

```
public class Range {
 public DateOnly begin { get; set; }
 public DateOnly end? { get; set; }
 public Range(DateOnly b, DateOnly e) {
  begin = b;
  end = e;
 }
}
```

I have a list of Ranges like as `List<Range>`, How can I filter by the range is in a date interval where the interval from and to is also a DateOnly?
I guess with `.Where(` but how can I implement when the end of range is nullable?

Comment: public DateOnly end?  --> public DateOnly? end   ---- ????

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title is a summary of your question, not a bunch of tags.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could coalesce?

```
.Where(r => date >= r.begin && date <= (r.end ?? DateOnly.MaxValue))
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
.Where(r => date > begin.Value && (!r.end.HasValue || date < r.end.Value))
```

essentially:

date is after begin and either (end is null) or (date is less than end)